# How can I UPDATE table using condition WHERE from another table in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I'm working with SQLite and I have two tables:

```
   table1                     table2
-------------             --------------
id                        id
value                     condition
```

Column "id" contains the same data. And I need to:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.value = 'Some value'
WHERE table2.condition = 'Some condition"
```

I tried to use **JOIN** and **FROM** for linking tables with "id" column, but this isn`t working in SQLite. Please help with syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery in the update, something like this:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET value = 'Some value'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2
              WHERE t2.id = table1.id AND
                    t2.condition = 'Some condition');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1** : Considering the two tables you have are "Table1" and "Table2", Updating Table1 can be done using a nested Select statement in which you will be selecting the data you need to update from Table2. For example:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET StudentID =
(
  SELECT RegNo
  FROM Table2 t
  WHERE StudentID = RegNo
);
```

You can have a look on this link which solves a similar question : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206317/update-values-in-one-table-from-data-in-another

**Method 2** : You can use a table join. Refer the same link given above.